# White flash when popping using pop gesture on iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

There's a white flash when starting to pop a screen with a swipe gesture, and stopping the swipe gesture mid way to cancel the pop.
It happens only when one of the view controllers has a transparent navigationBar background.

Is this a known iOS 13 bug?

First view controller:

```c
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
    [self.navigationItem.standardAppearance configureWithTransparentBackground];
}

@end
```

Second view controller:

```c
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
    [self.navigationItem.standardAppearance configureWithOpaqueBackground];
    [self.navigationItem.standardAppearance setBackgroundColor:UIColor.redColor];
}

@end
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The white space above and below your blue background suggests the issues run deeper.

Comment: @matt it doesn't seem related.. I removed that view and updated the gif

Comment: Okay, excellent. Well then it sounds like this is a variety of the well-known flash that comes from doing exactly what you're doing, i.e. you've got view controllers with different nav bar transparencies / visibility. Usually the flash is black rather than white but it seems like the same issue. File a bug report with Apple, is my advice.